# Linux: Can I install a OS from a snapshot/backup?

Tags: linux, boot, backup, arch-linux, iso-image

This idea has been inside my head for years. I tried creating my own Windows version, without certain processes and, with certain configurations, and mounting a custom installer (like a custom ISO inside a bootable media) where I install everything I want and it's ready to go. I'm about to install Arch Linux and I wonder if I can create a kind of screenshot of the system once it's finished, so I can save it on a USB and reinstall it many times on different computers. This ISO must have preinstalled drivers, a windows manager and a desktop environment, etcetera.

#### A few years ago,

I tried this with Windows, and I managed to create a custom ISO without some processes because I knew I wouldn't need them. But I wasn't able to create an ISO with preinstalled programs/drivers. So I used that image and then installed stuff manually. I know it's possible, but I can't find out how.

#### So...

I want to create a custom boot with my personal background, desktop environment, windows manager, my console... etc., So I format my pc and I don't need to spend too much time reinstalling my OS, which I'll use for work.

Comment: With Windows, one can use Sysprep to build an image with software and that works. Final customization needs to be done at the workstation. I have not seen such a counterpart for Linux (but there may be one). The term Snapshot does not normally apply here.

Comment: In principle this is doable, but you will need to fiddle around and resize hard drive partitions (either manually or using a script).   Depending on exactly how you want to do this, there are LOTS of ways to skin this cat, including taking an image you are happy with, then booting a USB disk and dumping the drive to a file (lots of ways and tricks to do this better), then you can decompress file to any drive the same size.  Linux is A lot more tolerant of different hardware types then Windows.

Comment: @davidgo so, can you give me a list of concepts or tools to investigate? Because you're telling me how to solve the problem without telling me how to solve the problem.

Comment: I"m both to expert and not expert enough.  (Hence the comment, not answer). There are too many possible solutions.  I might install Linux on a small disk (say 16 gig) and customise it. I'd then Dd the blank space with zero's.  Then I might boot another instance and gzip the entire 16 gig drive - partitions and all onto a basic bootable linux disk.  Then Id reverse this onto the cloned system and grow the drive...  Many tools, many possibilities, doubtless not the best solution...

Comment: Tools to use - see how far you can get wuth Ubuntu runnable YSB disk. Look at RUFUS.  ddrescue, fdisk, partitionmagic, You need to understand block devices.  If you learn how GRUB finds and loads partitions and initramdisks those can be very useful.   Thus just scratches the surface.

Comment: Maybe look at https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-iso-with-cubic/ (never used it). Also do a google search for "persistent bootable usb linux"

Comment: @davidgo thank you very much